# Knockback.js: How can I make the view update when backbone save updates the model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js, knockback.js

This is my first time working with [Knockback.js](http://kmalakoff.github.com/knockback/).

I'm working on a Knockback proof of concept, but I'm having a hard time getting the view model to update when I save a model. In this case, what happens is the server returns a new `Domain` object with the `id` field set, which means that the object now exists on the backend. Once that happens, I would like the UI to change to reflect the fact that it is now saved.

Here is the code I'm using:

```html
<table cellspacing="0" class="listing-table" id="domainListTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                Domain
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: domains">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!-- ko if:save -->
                    <a data-bind="attr: { href: domainEditLinkdomainId, title: domain},text : domain">
                        <span data-bind="text: domain"></span>
                    </a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot:save -->
                    <input type="text" maxlength="250" style="display:inline-block;" class="medium-text-field" data-bind="value: domain"></input>
                    <input data-bind="click: save" style="display:inline-block;"  type="submit" value="Save New Domain" alt="" title=""/>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<input data-bind="click: addDomain" type="submit" value="Add New Domain" alt="" title=""/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var Domain = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: function() {
          return {
            domain: "New Domain"
          };
        },
    });

    var Domains = {};

    Domains.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Domain,
        url: '/cms/rest/poc/${customerId}/domains/'
    });

    var domains = new Domains.Collection();
    domains.fetch();

    var DomainViewModel = kb.ViewModel.extend({
        constructor: function(model) {
            kb.ViewModel.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);

            var self = this;

            this.save = kb.observable(model, {
              key: 'save',
              read: (function() {
                return !model.isNew();
              }),
              write: (function(completed) {
                return model.save({}, {
                    wait: true,
                    success: function (model, response) {
                        console.log(model);
                        console.log(response);
                        console.log(self);
                    },
                    error: function(model, response) {
                        alert("Oh NooooOOOes you broked it!!!11!")
                    }
                });
              })
            }, this);

            this.domainEditLinkdomainId = ko.dependentObservable(function() { 
                if(!this.save())
                    return "";

                return "cms?action=domainDetail&domainID=" + this.model().id;
            }, this);
         }
    });

    var DomainsViewModel = function(collection) {
        this.domains = kb.collectionObservable(collection, { view_model: DomainViewModel });
        this.addDomain = function() {
            this.domains.push(new DomainViewModel(new Domain()));
        };
    };

    var domainsViewModel = new DomainsViewModel(domains);

    ko.applyBindings(domainsViewModel);
</script>
```

The problem seems to be that the `XMLHttpRequest` done by `model.save()` does not return until after the save `kb.observable` is read, and so the html part does not update successfully, since it still sees `model.isNew()` as true.

I've been messing around with a couple of different ideas, as you can probably see, including using the `valueHasMutated` method on an observable to indicate that the model has been updated, but I can't figure out how to do that either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are saving stuff to your model, the model should trigger different events depending on its state.

From Backbone docs:


`Calling save with new attributes will cause a "change" event immediately, a "request" event as the Ajax request begins to go
to the server, and a "sync" event after the server has acknowledged the successful change. Pass {wait: true} if you'd like to wait for the server before setting the new attributes on the model.` Could you not have one of your views listen to the event?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to a `change:id` event on the model.

This would only ever fire when a model's state has changed from new to persisted.